# From synchronous to asynchronous "Processing" when working with list chunks

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing module via class `Process` to do some not cpu-bound tasks, e.g. I/O, or web requests. If the tasks take too long the CPU reaches 100% of usage (all threads are waiting the data to return). I suspect  asynchronous execution solution but I have never done something like this. The code I am using is something like the following where I have a huge list and each process works on a chunk.

Could you please make a suggestion in this direction?

Thanks in advance!!

```
import multiprocessing
def getData(urlsChunk, myQueue):

    for url in urlsChunk:
       fp = urllib.urlopen(url)
       try:
           data = fp.read()
           myQueue.put(data)
       finally:
           fp.close()

    return myQueue

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
HUGEQ = manager.Queue()
urls = ['a huge list of url items']
chunksize = int(math.ceil(len(urls) / float(nprocs)))
for i in range(nprocs):
    p = Process(
                target = getData, # This is my worker
                args=(urls[chunksize * i:chunksize * (i + 1)],
                        MYQUEUE
                    )
                )
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

while True:
    try:
        MYQUEUEelem = MYQUEUE.get(block=False)
    except Empty:
        break
    else:
        'do something with the MYQUEUEelem'
```

Comment: I don't understand the while loop at the bottom. Shouldn't you be making a blocking call? The first time the child processes fall behind, the parent will get an Empty and break out of the processing loop.

Comment: Chunking is not a good idea when fetching urls. Chunking reduces the parent/child overhead by sending multiple requests at once. The down side is that the child now has to process all of them. If some urls are slow, the remaining urls on that client will have to wait, even if another child is done and ready to process more.

Comment: Could you explain a litle more about what do you mean by `blocking call` and child processes?

Comment: You are creating a set of child processes that fetch urls synchronously. getData takes 1 url, makes the request, waits for the request to complete and returns the result. Suppose you have 100 urls and 10 children. You could give 10 urls (chunks) to each child. But some urls take longer than others (maybe a lot longer) so some children finish before others. If you only hand down 1 url at at time (no chunk) then children that finish early take extra urls and you get done more quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), your code can be simplified:

```
import multiprocessing

def getData(url):
    fp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    try:
        return fp.read()
    finally:
        fp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':  # should protect the "entry point" of the program
    urls = ['a huge list of url items']
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for result in pool.imap(getData, urls, chunksize=10):
        # do something with the result
```

Comment: @Thoth, I think this will not take 100% cpu unless you do some heavy calculation in `do something with the result` part.

Comment: The `do something with the results` is saving data in a txt file. Is this logical?

Comment: @Thoth, Do you mean all urls' content into one file? Or in separated files? Both are possible.

Comment: Maybe my post was based in a the wrong assumption. The reason the cpu overhead was not the idle situation of the threads for the web response. However, the small-not cpu expensive-but big in number computations produced this situation.  Maybe by question based on the wrong assumption.

Comment: Anyway, is your snippet asynchronous? I mean after a web call the threads continue to do something else until the data returned? Moreover, can we do this map (`imap`) manually? I want to do the question more general rather that to delete it if that is necessary (with your permission).

Comment: @Thoth, This snippet is parallel rather than asynchronous. Statements after `for` statement will not be executed, the whole urls are downloaded and processed.

Comment: @Thoth, How about post a separated question?

Comment: I found very useful your code and I am interested about the execution inside the `for` loop. After a web call via a thread, the thread waits the data to return or does is make another web call? (The returned data are saved in the mean while I suppose if the aforementioned is true.)

Comment: @Thoth, If you use multiprocessing, multiple processes (not threads) are created and they are all run synchronously. `pool.*map*` sends tasks to them, wait for responses, handles one by one.